# ExpressJS Post download works but download windows wont appear?

Tags: node.js, express, post, download

im trying to create a download for a user but somehow my download doesnt work even tho it works?Let me explain :
Server post request :

```
app.post('/downloadRequest', function (req, res) {
                var fileName = "testname.txt";
                var file = __dirname +'/test.txt';
                res.download(file,fileName,function(err) {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log("downloaded");
                });
});
```

When im calling it,no error message appears. Also it shows "downloaded" in the console.Im clueless..

Comment: Have you tried changing `post` to `get`? Not related; use `path.join(__dirname, 'test.txt')` instead of +. Another test you can do; try using `res.sendFile` directly and see what happens

Comment: Are you sure your full path is correct? What does the fullpath looks like?

Comment: Yes, the path is correct. test.txt is in the same folder as the server.js script. I tried to use res.sendFile, its the same outcome as download. Server says the download "worked" but there is no download window on my html page. Also i would prefer to use post because in the function itself sql databases get changed and i heard you shouldnt do it with get.

Comment: If you're using chrome, close all instances and re-open chrome from your command prompt by doing this:  /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-logging=stderr (mac) or google-chrome --enable-logging=stderr (linux) . what error msg  do you see?